# Resource Bundle inheritance

Tags: java, jsf, resourcebundle

i am trying to do simple operations on a Resource bundle , i have read the following in an OCP book:
"if there is no match for the key at most specific bundle , compiler will look for more general one"

i have these properties files and their contents beneath each one:

```
Zoo_en_CA.properties
visitor=Canada visitor

Zoo_fr_CA.properties 
visitor=Canada visiteur

Zoo_en.properties
hello = Hello
open = is open

Zoo_fr.properties 
hello=Bonjour
open=est ouvert

Zoo.properties 
name= Vancouver Zoo
```

i write my code to use these files depends on what i  read but unfortunately MissResourceException is popup for me

here is my code:

```
public class UseZoo {

    public void use()
    {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "CA");
     ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Zoo", locale);
     System.out.print(rb.getString("hello"));
     System.out.print(". ");
     System.out.print(rb.getString("name"));
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(rb.getString("open"));
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(rb.getString("visitor"));
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        UseZoo z = new UseZoo(); 
        z.use();
    }
}
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: can you show your bundle configuration?

Comment: @canillas , it is already mentioned in the question at the first part

Comment: I don't see your ResourceBundle configuration anywhere. You only post name and content from your .properties and how you call the ResourceBundle but not your configuration...

Comment: @canillas what do you mean by configuration ?

Comment: Please take a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html) to understand resource bundles.

Comment: @user2780962 your configuration file. if you don't configure your ResourceBoundle before use it, how do you expect it works?

Answer (score 0):

If application is web app, check if your bundles are located under resources folder. 
In below example link you access the bundle through ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.MockBundle", Locale.FRANCE);

[Example image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCBmX.png)